# it is good to use only one model in whole project

Tags: codeigniter

- It is good habit to use only one model in whole project? and load that model in autoload only

  $autoload['model'] = array('data_model');

Answer (score 0):

No, Models are used to interact with data, if you use one model for the whole project, the functions that are not necessary will also be available for execution, using server resources making your project less efficient and make your project slow in execution.

If you use multiple models the server will have less overload as only those models with respective functions that are necessary for a page are getting loaded.

This is what is the concept of MVC.

Answer (score 0):

As a habit not it's not good, but there may be times when one model is all you need.

In most cases you'll want to break functionality down into different areas of an project, already mentioned are the likes of having users and something they do.  Putting everything in one place might seem easy enough at first, but goes against the MVC ideology of breaking things down into more manageable parts.

If there's a lot of functionality which is common in your application between models, then create a model for that and autoload it.  You can then either have your models extend that model, or call the functionality within from the auto loaded model.

As a general rule, for every main table in your database you should have a model.  You won't need one for each link table, but for each main item of your project you should have a model.

Take a basic blog, for instance.  It will have two parts:

- Users
- Posts

While it is possible to put everything in one large file, it would be better to break it down into a User model and a Post model.  If you had everything as part of a Blog model, then you'd either only have a Blog controller to call it, or you'd have a User controller and a Post controller which would call the same model to do different things.

It may seem easier on a personal project where you're going to be the only developer, but anything with more than one person contributing (or anything which is going to be a sane project) should be broken down into parts as small as possible so they can be easily maintained going forwards.